Safe Disposal of Rags Used to Wipe Up Motor Oil
Recently, I changed the oil on my lawn mower. Foolishly, I didn't use a funnel, so things got messy and I used the paper towels that I had on hand to clean up my mess.
Given that motor oil needs to be safely disposed of, my intuition is that I should take care when disposing of the soiled towels. However, I am struggling to find any clear guidance on whether special care is needed and where to dispose of them.
Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Rags with any combustible or flammable substance on them are to be stored in a covered metal container.  How to dispose of?  That should be directed to your local waste/ recycling center.

Where you live might have a hazardous waste site.  They can tell you the exact way to get rid of the paper towels.  I do not think motor oil is as bad to start fire/burn like some chemicals, but placing them in a can that can be sealed(old paint can) will not hurt.

Motor oil is not s curing oil, so there isn't a spontaneous combustion risk. It is, if course, flammable, may contain toxic combustion products, and is generally a pollutant. Check with your local waste disposal department to find out how they want you to handle this; some will want it treated as a hazmat.

New oil is not all that toxic, it's just mineral oil.  The issue with used oil is heavy metal contaminants which were rubbed off into the oil from engine parts.
